# Cast generic type T into Class<T>

Tags: java, class, object, types, casting

How do I cast a generic type `T` into an object as `Class<T>`?

Something like `Class<T> T.class` or `Class<T> T.getClass()` does not work, because `T` is no variable.

A function should look like this:

```
public Class<T> getType() {
 return // Class of T
}
```

Background info:
 I have some classes `Class1<T>`, `Class2<T>`, ... which all `extend ParentClass<T>`. `ParentClass` has the function `getType()`.
I'm looking for an more elegant way to get the type then just creating a variable `Class<?> type` and saving the type that way.

Comment: Can you show your code. Where do you want to do that and why?

Comment: Welcome to the horrible world of type erasure.  That's generally impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't know `T` at runtime (because of [Type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)).

Basically, `MyWonderfulClass<String>` will become `MyWonderfulClass<Object>` at runtime so you don't have any chance to retrieve it except if you directly give the class in the constructor or in a setter :

```
//class is a reserved keyword so I call it clazz instead.
public MyClass(Class<T> clazz) {
  this.clazz = clazz;
}

public Class<T> getType() {
  return this.clazz;
}
```

You can also force your subclasses to implement `getType() : Class<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
public class Parent<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public Parent(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<T> getType() {
        return clazz;
    }
}

public class Foo<T> extends Parent {

    public Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew that, just interested if there is an eleganter way of doing this (see Background Info). Thanks anyway.